# Help with finding TextBox inside CellEditingTemplate

Tags: wpf, datagridtemplatecolumn

Can you give me some idea about how to find TextBox inside CellEditingTemplate?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you want to find your control..? The CellEditing template will be loaded only when the grid enters editing mode.

Check the following links and see if it helps

[DataGrid: Help accessing a control defined in a CellEditingTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/739084/217880)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/e4cc93eb-9ded-4eb1-a7d2-cedda7eedb70

[DataGridTemplateColumn with DatePicker requires three clicks to edit the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5176226/datagridtemplatecolumn-click-problem/5176728#5176728)

Comment: Hi Thanks for reply. I am actully having problem with implement "Delete" function for DataGridTemplateColumn without going to edit mode. When user clicks the "Delete" key, I want to clear the content in my DataGridTemplateColumn. I know there will be a "TextBlock" inside "CellTemplate" and a "TextBox" inside "CellEditingTemplate". Thanks